# How to get once my last location in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-maps

I want to know how can I get my last known location (GPS or network provided). I'm asking this because I know how to get my location but it's going to be updated periodically and I just want it once and no any more.

Here's my actual code:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cambio posicion "+location.getProvider(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     this.marca.title("Mi ubicacion");
     this.marca.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));

     mMap.addMarker(this.marca);

     this.camara = CameraPosition.builder()
             .bearing(0)
             .zoom(15)
             .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
             .tilt(30)
             .build();

     mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(this.camara));


}
```

I'm using LocationManager. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LocationManager` and you just want to get last location **once**. You can remove listen location update after first `onLocationChanged` like

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mListener);
}
```

Another solution I think it may help is. 
You can use `GoogleLocationService` instead of `LocationManager`. Then you can use this method for [get last known location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known)

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fused Location Provider, you can stop listening for location changed event after the first one like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("onLocationChanged", new Gson().toJson(location));
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}
```